Interpretation of Spin Density for FeCl₂ Monolayer Visualized in VESTA
I have performed spin density calculations for an FeCl₂ monolayer using VASP and visualized the results in VESTA. While I can see the spin density distribution, I am seeking guidance on how to interpret these results.

